# My MongoDB free cluster suddenly stops working

Tags: reactjs, node.js, database, mongodb, backend

```
2281984:error:10000438:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR:..\..\third_party\boringssl\src\ssl\tls_record.cc:592:SSL alert number 80
```

This is the error message I get while trying to connect to my cluster using MongoDB Compass. I checked Atlas and it says at the top: "We are deploying your changes (current action: creating a plan)". I have never seen anything like that but I've been using this cluster for a few months.

I tried connecting multiple times via Compass but every time I tried there was the same error message. I also had no success trying to connect in NodeJS, this is the error i get:

```
MongoDB connection error: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (E:\1. Programiranje\Web projekti\Balkanflix\Balkanflix\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:788:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (E:\1. Programiranje\Web projekti\Balkanflix\Balkanflix\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:763:11)
    at async connectDB (E:\1. Programiranje\Web projekti\Balkanflix\Balkanflix\server\config\db.js:5:9) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-fiu19tn-shard-00-01.bmscihv.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-fiu19tn-shard-00-02.bmscihv.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-fiu19tn-shard-00-00.bmscihv.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-jj3mwx-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

My colleague also tried and he couldn't connect so I guess the problem is not only on my local machine. I tried searching on the MongoDB community and there was nothing like this.

Comment: *One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted.* https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/ - is your IP whitelisted? Easy to check when you connect to the cluster in the web UI. If your IP is not whitelisted, you should get a banner telling you so. The web UI might also give you a hint regarding the first message.

Comment: @Markus no my IP is indeed whitelisted and I've also tried to add option to Access from anywhere and still no results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using shared or serverless versions of mongodb?
There's an active issue with it, they have posted about it on the MongoDB Cloud Status channel. You can also see it when you open their support box on the bottom right corner.

> Update - We have partially remediated the issue.  However, metrics for Atlas Shared Tier and Atlas Serverless clusters are still experiencing delays. Changes to Atlas clusters (including IP Access List modifications, topology and tier changes, or the creation of new clusters) may still be experiencing some delays.
> Jan 17, 2024 - 13:33 UTC

Comment: thanks but I'm using the only free version which is shared if im not wrong