# Mongo Db Atlas - "Your cluster is being created.." stuck forever how to fix it

Tags: mongodb

Hello I am currently doing a MERN stack application and i want to use database from mongoDb but when i am trying to create the Database it is stuck on Your Cluster is being created, I setted up my username and password, also I setted up my IP address to 0.0.0.0.

I tried setting up my DNS to 8.8.8.8 because I thought it might be a connection issue but it didn't fix it keep in my mind I am using Windows 11, If anyone knows how to fix it please write it I would really appreciate it

Comment: If MongoDB Atlas is stuck creating your cluster, you'll need to contact their support.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77833096/20042973) from earlier which feels related

Comment: Customer Service questions are off-topic here - see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) Also, please be mindful of tags - this question has nothing to do with [tag:reactjs] or [tag:mern] (I removed these, accordingly)

Comment: @user20042973 - that other question/answer is off-topic here as well.